# Identify min date in excel field using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a excel file with one column as project assignments. A sample value of this column is given below :

```
XXX E(10aug15-30sep16),YYY G(30nov15-29jul16),ZZZZ C(18jan16-23dec16),AAA B(04jan16-28jul16)
```

I have to write a formula to give me min of all dates identified. I know, I can use Macros, but due to security issues, our organization wants to avoid macros.

The output of above field should be `10-Aug-15`. Please note, each date will always be of 7 characters.

I was using the below array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) to find the max date :

```
=IF('Supply Report'!S2="","",MAX(IFERROR(VALUE(MID('Supply Report'!S2,ROW($A$1:$A$1000),7)),0)))
```

Modifying `MAX` to `MIN` is not working.

Comment: "The output of above field should be 04-Jan-16." Why is the min of all dates not 10-Aug-15?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, my bad. Yes, it should be 10-AUG-15. 

Updated the text.

Comment: `{=IF('Supply Report'!S2="","",MIN(IFERROR(VALUE(MID('Supply Report'!S2,ROW($A$1:$A$1000),7)),9^99)))}`

Comment: Thanks, stupid mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

**EXPLANATION**

The first thing is to explain what your formula is doing. It loops through your string creating an array of separate strings of length 7 like so:

```
"XXX E(1"
"XX E(10"
"X E(10a"
" E(10au"
"E(10aug"
"(10aug1"
"10aug15"
"0aug15-"
...etc
```

Then perform `VALUE` on those strings, which will return a number if the string is in a correct date format or and error otherwise

```
VALUE("XXX E(1") = #VALUE!
VALUE("XX E(10") = #VALUE!
VALUE("X E(10a") = #VALUE!
VALUE(" E(10au") = #VALUE!
VALUE("E(10aug") = #VALUE!
VALUE("(10aug1") = #VALUE!
VALUE("10aug15") = 42226
VALUE("0aug15-") = #VALUE!
...etc
```

Then using the `IFERROR(formula,0)` function replaces the error terms  with zeros so that your array looks like this:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0,42226,0,...}
```

So when you are performing a `MIN` on that array, it is returning 0 rather than the smallest date.

**SOLUTION**

Your solution with `MIN`:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:$A$1000),7)),99999))
```

Works because it creates and array like so:

```
{99999,99999,99999,99999,99999,99999,42226,99999,...}
```

And takes the `MIN` of that.

**Alternatively**, you can also use `LARGE` in the following way:

```
=LARGE(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:$A$1000),7)),0),8)
```

That is, it is finding the eighth largest date in the array with zeros, which should also be the smallest if there are exactly eight dates.

Enter it as an array formula - using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Hi @ShubhamGupta. If this answers your question please accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

=IF('Supply Report'!S2="","",MIN(IFERROR(VALUE(MID('Supply Report'!S2,ROW($A$1:$A$1000),7)),999999999999999)))

Comment: You get an upvote if you will explain how this formula works and why with MAX a IFERROR(..., 0) is needed while with MIN a IFERROR(..., 999999999999999) is needed.

Comment: The answer above explains it :)